# Binary trees implementation in the back-end or front-end

Tags: javascript, python, tree

I've learned about Binary trees and how it makes searching alot efficient. I know databases support Binary tree searching, and there are libraries you can utilize to make this type of search in languages like javascript and python. My question is, would there be a common case where you'd have to implement in the front-end or back-end a binary tree search (you setup a classes like tree and node)? Given example you have RESTful APIs that you can get or insert data, would your javascript or backend language need a Binary tree implementation?

Comment: As a note, the common use case for front end tree searching is searching the DOM, often done using library or helper routines such as  [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).  [`document.createTreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker), introduced in DOM2, provides an alternative to writing a DOM search from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, I'm no expert, you would typically see more advanced trees like [B-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) in database and filesystem implementations.

This is kind of an ambiguous question because there's always some odd problem out there that can really benefit from such, but you typically want to optimize the database to avoid implementing something like a tree yourself.

Edit: By optimizing database to avoid trees, I am referring to things like design, query optimization, and limiting results.

You want your front-end to be as responsive as possible so using trees would imply you have large amounts of data, which will inevitably slow down your UI. You're better off limiting the amount of data and paginating the results; to understand why think of the application through a user's eyes - if it doesn't feel like it's working... then it must be broken.